# How to beep different for JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, beep

How I can generate different beep sounds for different types of messages (e.g. Warning, information, question) using JOptionPane in java. As in windows OS there are different beep sound for each message that appeared to user.
Currently I am using the following to generate beep, but it beeps same every time.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
JJOptionPane.showMessageDialog( myFrame, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
```

I want a different beep for warning message, information message and question message. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[beep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep%28%29) issues a request to the underlying operating system to emit an audio beep. On certain platforms such as Windows, the "default sound" is played.

Rather than attempting to interface with specific platforms, it is simpler to play a corresponding sound file prior to displaying the dialog:

```
AudioInputStream ais = 
     AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/information.wav"));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
clip.start();            
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
clip.close();
```

Comment: Is there any need to close the `clip` and `ais` or not, but I think it must be closed. Is it necessary to put my audio in the resources, but I want to package the Application later, it will work fine or not?

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that I  should manually play the audio depending on the message type. But I want that I simply write the `JOptionPane.shwMessageDialog(...);` and Java should sound beep for me depending on the message type. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes its good practice to call `Clip#close` to release any resources being used. Using `getResource` is the way to go esp if youre packaging the application.

Comment: Any need to close `AudioInputStream`? What is meant by esp?

Comment: To answer your 2nd question, a request is made to the native OS when beep is called. Go for `clip.start` for cross platform.

Comment: No need to close `AudioStream`. `Clip#close` will take care of that. Time to start reading those [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#close()). esp = _especially_

Comment: Ok I am going with `clip.start()`.